# Are there any events triggered when any / all the elements of an ItemsControl have been added to the VisualTree?

Tags: events, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

`FrameworkElement.Loaded` happens when the container has been added to the tree.

I need to do some custom scrolling based on the measurement of all the databound items added to the `ItemsControl`.

I *can* wire up to an event like `LayoutUpdated`, then trace through descendants, counting the children but that's pretty heavy work.

Are there any events triggered when any / all the databound elements of an ItemsControl have been added to the VisualTree?

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the ItemsControl for best performance of getting the items:

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        var listViewItem = base.GetContainerForItemOverride();

        // process the ListViewItem

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Useful information, but unfortunately not an answer to the problem I have.

Comment: That's assuming the `ItemsControl` is a `ListView`. If it's just an `ItemsControl` - you would replace ListView with ItemsControl and listViewItem with contentPresenter in my code. When you know the number of containers returned is what you expect to load - that would be the time when all your elements have been added to the tree. Bear in mind that if the ItemsPanel is a virtualizing panel - not all of the items would actually be usually loaded at the same time. There is no single reliable event to know that all of them are added.